# Fastest way to get rid of repeat items?

Tags: ios, objective-c

In objective-c, the fastest way to delete repeat object.

**like**

I have a array:

```
@[@"1",@"2",@"4",@"4",@"4",@"2"] .
```

Output the answer

```
@[@"1",@"2",@"4"];
```

Comment: Try this code . `NSOrderedSet *orderedSet = [NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithArray:yourArray];
NSArray *arrayWithoutDuplicates = [orderedSet array];`

Answer (score 1):

```
NSArray<NSString *> *unique = [NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithArray: @[@"1",@"2",@"4",@"4",@"4",@"2"]].array;
```